# iOS Youtube API v3 retrieve my channels

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, youtube-data-api

[IOS SWIFT]

I have a problem with youtube api v3, and I really hit a dead end

So, in my app I have newest GoogleSign-In implemented

```
let newScope: Array =
        ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube",
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl",
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"]
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = newScope
```

This shows how I add new scopes.

I successfully sign in user and retreive user id, it's data, access_token etc.

Now that the user is signedin, I need to get his youtubeId/channelId.

I did some research and I found that I can get my channel id with: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&mine=true&key={API_KEY_HERE}`

I even tried to send access_token in url, but with no luck..

But something is wrong and I get 401 status code -

> The request uses the `mine` parameter but is not properly
>   authorized.

What am I doing wrong?

Here I tested and everything works fine: `https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list`

result here in sandbox:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XXXXXXX\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"XXXXX\"",
   "id": "XXXXX",
   "googlePlusUserId": "ID_ID_ID"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Anyone have idea? solution? proposal?
Thankyou very much

In fact, why am I not authorized if I just successfully signedIn myself??

Tried even adding header for authorization:

```
Bearer {id_access_token}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

Yes, the header needs to be send. The only problem was with token!

When the signIn is successful, you get

```
GIDGoogleUser
```

instance.

That - lets call it "user", have .authentication with userID, idToken and accessToken

In documentation there is only mention of idToken, so I thought that this is actually the access token. How silly of me :/

Lesson learned!

Comment: Hi, could you explain your solution more? This is what I’m doing:

```let finalQuery = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?key=\(ProfileNetwork.apiKey)&part=snippet&mine=true"```

The error I get is: `The request uses the mine parameter but is not properly authorized`

I'm sending the key I originally got for my app, and might just be a basic YouTube API key. I get the user object when I log, which has a bunch of tokens inside of it. I'm not sure if I need those instead. I've tried a bunch of combinations of querys and none of them work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @tokan_one I really not remember which key was actually the right one, but definitely one of those keys in user object must be correct

Comment: Thanks @virusss8, I figured it out!  For any future person visiting, you need to include the HTTP Header `{"Authorization": "Bearer <#accessToken#>"}`